# how to filter data when select value from dropdown bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

in my web page have a dropdown (bootstrap) with different items, i want to filter the elements are showing by this dropdown.

My dropdown looks like this:

[image]

The code for this:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown todos" id="todos">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle botn-todos" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Todos
            <span class="caret caret-posicion"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu ancho-todos" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="status-1" name="1"><span> Todos</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="status-3" name="3"> En camino</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="status-9" name="9"> En camino - 2do intento</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="status-6" name="6"> Entregado</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="status-12" name="12"> Entregado al 2do intento</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="nose" name=""> No se puede entregar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><input value="1" name="busqueda1" type="radio" class="status-7" name="7"> Cancelado</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

The items that i want to filter looks like:

[image]

I don't know if can help me the attribute onchnage inside dropdown, but the code for filter i dont have any idea.

Dropdown item's have a class, name that match with the element of the list.

Comment: There are numerous tutorials as well as plugins for filtering the dom...not to mention lots of posts on this site. What research have you done and what have you tried? Yes...everything will be dependent on the events in your dropdown

Comment: For starters, you should probably use a label instead of an anchor tag.  labels provide you the benefit of being able to click either the radio button itself or the text associated with it.

Comment: i try to understand if i can do this with similar functions like data table

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set a class to each piece of data you want to filter based on the selected radio option. After you've selected one, go through whatever data you need to filter and for the ones that don't have the id matching up to what you're trying to filter, add the hide class to them.

Comment: I need to put onchange tag in my dropdown or is not necesary?

Comment: Yeah, you'd want to keep track of what you've chosen so that you can filter it. So maybe onchange you'll call a function and pass in the type based on the selected dropdown item.